# What is a proper way to connect to AWS Elasticache (Redis cluster) from Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jedis, amazon-elasticache, redisson

I'm new to **AWS Elasticache redis**, and I got below endpoint.

[image]

I'm confused in either using **Jedis** and **Redisson**, because both provides single connection and cluster connection class.

Like in **Jedis**, for a single connection we can use:

```
Jedis conn = new Jedis("endpoint_address");
```

And for cluster connection we use:

```
Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNodes = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();
jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort("redis_cluster_ip", 7379));
JedisCluster jc = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNodes);
```

These option also occur when I want to use **Redisson**. I'm not try to compare these two lib, my question is: WHICH ONE is the right method of connecting to *AWS Redis Elasticache* cluster, when you only have one end-point and still can utilize AWS auto scaling feature?

Expected answer is: use SINGLE or CLUSTER MODE.

Thanks :)

Comment: Yess... I'm running this from an EC2 instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you have the redis cluster configured. Whether or not cluster mode is enabled.

You can find it in the console

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Endpoints.html

> Redis (cluster mode disabled) clusters, use the Primary Endpoint for
> all write operations. Use the individual Node Endpoints for read
> operations (In the API/CLI these are referred to as Read Endpoints).
>
> Redis (cluster mode enabled) clusters, use the cluster's Configuration
> Endpoint for all operations. You must use a client that supports Redis
> Cluster (Redis 3.2). You can still read from individual node endpoints
> (In the API/CLI these are referred to as Read Endpoints).

Or with the AWS CLI

```
aws elasticache describe-cache-clusters \
    --cache-cluster-id mycluster \
    --show-cache-node-info
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticache/describe-cache-clusters.html

> ConfigurationEndpoint -> (structure) Represents a Memcached cluster
> endpoint which, if Automatic Discovery is enabled on the cluster, can
> be used by an application to connect to any node in the cluster. The
> configuration endpoint will always have .cfg in it. Example:
> mem-3.9dvc4r.cfg.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:11211

Answer (score 0):

You should use Replicated configuration in Redisson for AWS Elasticache Redis or other similar hosted services. The usage is described in the [documentation](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/2.-Configuration#25-replicated-mode).